# Jenkins pass json file to triggered downstream job

Tags: file, jenkins, triggers, jobs

I have a job that has a json file in its parameters.  I have this job trigger another job and it needs to pass the parameters. I have 'Current build parameters' enabled, but it does not pass files.  How can I get it to pass the json file to the triggered job.

I did have this working before, we were on 2016 verion of jenkins and recently upgraded to 2.286.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every matching file, invoke one build worked to pass the file.  Just typed in the name of the file that I have in the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the breaking change that your Jenkins might have experienced, but as a workaround, you can assign a global environment variable in Configure Jenkins to point a path to your JSON file.

That variable will be accessible to all jobs, and they can easily refer to it.

Comment: figured it out.  For every matching file, invoke one build did the trick

Comment: @ghost654 That's great! You used the plugin for this, right? I do recall there being this setting where individual files can invoke new build. I forgot the name of the plugin.

Comment: yeah parameterized trigger plugin